# 100% Scrolling Y Canvas using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I use JS once every 3 years and I'm surprised at how it somehow still gets substantially easier to understand despite the gaps.

I want a random, blurred dot background for my wordpress. I managed to pull [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zw23q4vs/) together using other posts from here. Works exactly how I want it to.

Now, to get it as my background in my Wordpress theme, I have it call the canvas.

**Javascript**

```
var c = document.createElement('canvas'),
  document.createElement('canvas').style.position = "relative",
  document.createElement('canvas').style.zIndex = "2",
    context = c.getContext('2d');


window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

    function resizeCanvas() {
            c.width = window.innerWidth;
            c.height = document.body.scrollHeight;
      
      
            /**
             * Circles.
             */
            drawStuff(); 
    }
    resizeCanvas();

    function drawStuff() {
// dot count
const dots = 7;
// max distance from the center
const radius = 2000;


var createDots = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= dots; i++) {
        context.beginPath();
        const dist = (Math.random()) * radius;
        var rand_x = radius * Math.random();
        var rand_y = radius * Math.random();
        context.arc(rand_x, rand_y, 90, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fillStyle = "#ed194f";
        //context.filter = "blur(180px)";
        context.shadowBlur = 160;
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();
    }
}

createDots();    }


document.body.style.background = 'url(' + c.toDataURL() + ')';
```

**(Possibly useless) CSS**

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; } /* to remove the top and left whitespace */

html, body { width:100%; height:100%; } /* just to be sure these are full screen*/

canvas { display:block;
width: 100%;
    height: 100%;} /* To remove the scrollbars */
```

I have a few issues:

1. It's Y should scroll. It's currently limited to the height of the viewport and repeats.
2. It's not as random as it is in the fiddle. The dots tend to stay roughly in a line.
3. I switched to shadowBlur for Safari, but it's still not blurring.

There may be some extraneous things in there–if so, please let me know as I'm very eager to learn. [This](https://portfolio.melanie-patterson.com) is the site (you have to toggle off the #fff bg of `.jupiterx-main` to see it in action–yet another work in progress). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I just answered my own #3. `shadowBlur` needs a `shadowColor` defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked at it long enough and was able to answer #3. `shadowBlur` needs a `shadowColor` defined.

`context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'; context.fill(); context.shadowColor = '#F03C69'; context.shadowBlur = 40;`

This unfortunately yields the faintest of (but still noticeable) circles. It doesn't achieve the blown out look I'm looking for from `context.filter = "blur(180px)";`

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tfe1vqmc/) it is.